# Cisco SG300 switch does not send RADIUS messages to server for 802.1x

Tags: cisco, switch, 802.1, nps

I want to eventually configure the SG300 to authenticate wired clients with 802.1x and Microsoft NPS (RADIUS). I am currently testing this setup using a single port (Port 7) on my SG300, a test machine, and an AD based Network Policy Server.

The problem I have is that when I change the Administrative Port Control for Port 7 to Force Authorized, I see this log entry:

Informational   %SEC-I-PORTAUTHORIZED: Port gi7 is Authorized

And then when I change the port control to Auto the port immediately changes to Unauthorized and I see this log entry:

Warning   %SEC-W-PORTUNAUTHORIZED: Port gi7 is unAuthorized

However I never see any RADIUS messages being sent from the SG300 to my RADIUS server or from the SG300 to the test machine plugged into port 7. I am using WireShark on my RADIUS server to watch for messages from the SG300 IP Address and I'm using WireShark on a second test machine that is configured to monitor the NIC card in the test machine plugged into port 7 (I'm using Hyper-V and its facilities for this NIC monitoring setup.)

Here is my configuration:

- Switch        - 10.1.1.3
- RADIUS (Microsoft NPS)- 10.1.1.15
- Switch Usage Type - All (Login and 802.1x)

Port 7 configuration:

- VLAN Mode is General
- Host Authentication is Single Host Authentication
- Administrative Port Control is Auto
- RADIUS VLAN Assignment is Disabled
- Guest VLAN is Enabled
- 802.1x Based Authentication is Enable d

Additional Configurations under Security - 802.1x/MAC/Web Authentication:

- Port Based Authentication is Enabled
- Authentication Method is RADIUS
- Guest VLAN is Enabled
- Guest VLAN ID is 2
- All of my VLANs are enabled for Authentication

One last note:

The SG300 uses the same RADIUS server for management console access and it works without problem. When I log into the switch, WireShark shows the RADIUS messages from the switch to the RADIUS server and back. So I know RADIUS is configured correctly on the switch.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Experiencing more or less the same thing. I had it working at one moment but it stopped and I don't why. Must be something that I did, but I wouldn't know what.